# Check if Python list elements are in a Pandas dataframe row and append to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

| Casa | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Solo Deportes | Paleta De Padel Adidas Metalbone CTRL |
| Solo Deportes | Zapatillas Running Under Armour Charged Stamin... |
| Solo Deportes | Rompeviento Con Capucha Reebok Woven Azu |

and a List:

> Maestro_Marcas=['Adidas', 'Reebebok','Under Armour']

How can I check each row of df['Name'], see if the row contains a value of the list, and in that case get the value of the list and put it in the new column?. The result should be something like this:

| Casa | Name | Marca |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Solo Deportes | Paleta De Padel Adidas Metalbone CTRL | Adidas |
| Solo Deportes | Zapatillas Running Under Armour Charged Stamin... | Under Armour |
| Solo Deportes | Rompeviento Con Capucha Reebok Woven Azu | Reebok |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `findall`

```
df['Marca'] = df['Name'].str.findall('|'.join(Maestro_Marcas))
```

Notice,it will return a list of finding, if two items found within one Name, it will return both.

To match the output you need

```
 df['Marca'] = df['Name'].str.findall('|'.join(Maestro_Marcas)).str[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use apply with a function such that:

```
Maestro_Marcas=['Adidas', 'Reebebok','Under Armour']

def is_exist(name):
    for i in Maestro_Marcas:
        if i in name:
            return i

df['Marca']  = df.apply(lambda x: is_exist(x['Name']), axis=1)
```

desired result:

```
    Casa            Name                                                 Marca   
0   Solo Deportes   Paleta De Padel Adidas Metalbone CTRL               Adidas
1   Solo Deportes   Zapatillas Running Under Armour Charged Stamin...   Under Armour
2   Solo Deportes   Rompeviento Con Capucha Reebok Woven Azu        None
```

I'm quite sure you should improve the function at one point for `Reebebok` vs `Reebok`  adjust as you see fit.